# permutations and transpositions in even and odd cases

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Say we had some $\sigma = (1, 2)(2, 3)...(n-1 ,n)$ could someone explain why this formula doesn't hold for odd n?

For instance, $n = 2m+1$ $\sigma = (1,2)...(2m-2,2m-1)(2m, 2m+1)$, why does that not work?

Comment: Why don't you try to decompose an odd permutation with the formula first?

Comment: @nameless I've tried and have been unable too, for instance the cycle $(1,2,3,4) = (1,4)(1,3)(1,2)$ with is odd but $(1,4)(1,3)(1,3) = (1,2)(2,3)(3,4)(2,3)(1,2)(1,3)(1,2)$ so it seems as though it doesn't work... I don't know why?

Comment: Warz: $(1, 2, 3, 4) = (1, 2)(2, 3)(3, 4)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n = 2m+1$, then we have, for a cycle of length $n$, [note, we need to use $m = 0$ for $n = 1$]:

$$(1, 2)(2, 3) \ldots(2m - 2, 2m - 1)(2m, 2m + 1)$$

Note that the first transposition starts with an odd number, and the last transposition starts with an even number: this makes an even number of transpositions, which is correct, since a cycle of an odd length is even.  So the algorithm works fine for odd and even $n$.

A permutation $\sigma$ is deemed even or odd based on whether it can be expressed only as a product of an even number of transpositions or only as an odd number of transpositions, respectively.

It is **not** deemed even or odd based on the length(s) of its cycle(s).

Simple example: $n = 3$ (odd $n$)

$$\sigma = (1, 2, 3) = \underbrace{(1, 2)(2, 3)}_{\large 2\;\text{transpositions}}$$

$2$ is clearly even. Therefore, $\sigma$ is an *even* permutation.

Comment: say n = 7, then we get $\sigma = (1,2)(3,4)(5,6)(6,7)$ using the formula, but $ 5 \to 6$ and $7 \to 6$ $7 \not = 5$, how is this possible?

Comment: No, if $n = 7$, we have $(1, 2)(2, 3)(3, 4)(4, 5)(5, 6)(6, 7)$. You need to apply the transpositions from right to left to reconstruct a permutation.  Recall, order matters, in non-disjoint cycles of a permutation. Transpositions are usually not disjoint.

Comment: could you please explain why if we had $\sigma = (1,2)(2,3)$ why is this valid? It takes 2 to 1, and 2 to 3 - a permutation is supposed to be a bijective, how should I read this out?

Comment: Right to left, remember? $1\to 1, \;1\to 2.$ Next, from the right again: $2\to 3, \;3\to 3.$ Next, again from the right: $3\to 2,\; 2\to 1$. That gives us, in summary: $\;1 \to 2,\; 2\to 3,\;  3\to 1\;$ or $(1, 2, 3)$